# Read latest entry in a file and compare with a string and then uninstall powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some help in reading latest entry in a file for two strings and then save that name do an un installation of that driver .I wrote this for searching but seems to return true for every instance.

```
$filename = "\\SigCap.log"
$md = "Device is missing"
$DeviceArray = "Sigcap"

$ErrStrng = [Regex]::Matches($filename,$md) | Measure-Object -Maximum Index
$Devstrng = [Regex]::Matches($filename,$DeviceArray) | Measure-Object -Maximum Index
If($Devstrng.Maximum -eq $ErrStrng.Maximum) 
{ 
  write-output "yes"
Write-host $DeviceArray

} 
else 
{ 
write-output "no" 
Write-host $DeviceArray
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you're using `[regex]::Matches()` incorrectly, but I'm not going to go there right now. Instead use the `-Match` operator in a `Where` statement since it uses RegEx by default. When used with the `Get-Content` command using the `-Tail` parameter this could be simple.

```
$LastLine = Get-Content $File -Tail 1
If($LastLine -match $md -and $LastLine -match $DeviceArray){
    "yes"
}Else{
    "no"
}
Write-host $DeviceArray
```

I think that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Ok, after reading your comments, I think this will do what you want:

```
$filename = "\\SigCap.log"
$md = "Device is missing"
$DeviceArray = "Sigcap"
$ErrStrng = select-string -Path $filename -Pattern $md |select -last 1 -expand LineNumber
$Devstrng = select-string -Path $filename -Pattern $devicearray |select -last 1 -expand LineNumber
If($Devstrng -eq $ErrStrng) 
{ 
  write-output "yes"
Write-host $DeviceArray

} 
else 
{ 
write-output "no" 
Write-host $DeviceArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @TheMadTechnician,this is what i get when i do like that ,also I cannot tail it as i need latest entry to do string match file can be big.Cannot convert value "sigcap" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was
not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\a036785\desktop\scripts\test\stringcompare.ps1:6 char:5
+ If ($File -match $md -and $File -match -$Device)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Comment: I was able to fix that ,thanks for your help,however I still need to get the latest of maximum entry , thats why I used maximum as Tailing might not yield correct results

Comment: Using `Get-Content $file -Tail 1` gets the last 1 line of the file. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: I do not want the last line, I want the last instance , example For example in this list last line is bar , but I want to find last instance of foo

foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
bar @TheMadTechnician

Comment: So you are searching a file for two strings, and want to see if the last instance for each string is on the same line?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking at ,its an array of few characters but if i get this fixed, I can run the array

Comment: this is what i get after i execute that  select : Property "index" cannot be found.
At C:\Users\a036785\desktop\scripts\test\stringcompare3.ps1:6 char:57
+ $ErrStrng = select-string -Path $filename -Pattern $md |select -last 1
-expand i ...

Comment: Sorry, not sure where I got Index from. That should be LineNumber. I'll have the answer updated in a moment.